# Why isn't h2 appearing anywhere on the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning HTML and CSS and I tried making my very first webpage but got stuck when I realized my h2 is not appearing anywhere on the page. Sorry Im a noob and have no idea what I did wrong. Please help! Thank you!

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white
}

a:hover{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
}

header h1{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
body{
    background-color: red;
}
nav{
    margin-right: 38%;
}
h2{
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TryOne</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The header is probably sitting on top of it. If you use the inspector and hover over the h2 tag in the element tree you'll see it outlined on the page.

Comment: If you starting out in html you could us these free tools  - http://lifehacker.com/5579328/five-best-wysiwyg-html-editors these are WYSIWYG Editors and You can easily do create something visually and see automatically generated html for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your header is fixed ...  You need to move your div down with margin ..[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cxw626ro/)

```
<header>
    <h1>My Portfolio</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="DIV">
    <h2>Hello!</h2>
</div>
```

--

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;

}
ul{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white
}

a:hover{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
}

header h1{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
body{
    background-color: red;
}
nav{
    margin-right: 38%;
}
h2{
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
}
#DIV{
  position:absolute;
margin-top: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to your use of a fixed header.

Take a look at this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXpggN

All I did was put some padding on the top of the div with the h2 in it, which brought it out from underneath the header. For future reference, a fixed position header will float above the rest of the contents, so the next elements that you add are going to begin appearing right at the very top of the body because the header div floating up top there is not occupying any space on the main body page.

If you ever want to organize your divs in a manner such as this, you just need to specify the z-index values of the divs. In this case though, all you needed was to push the first element (h2 div) down a bit.

```
position:inherit; padding-top:110px;
```

Answer (score 0):

your header overwrite other tag.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
header{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white
}

a:hover{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
}

header h1{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
body{
    background-color: back;
}
nav{
    margin-right: 38%;
}
h2{
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TryOne</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div>
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS:

```
h2 {
color: blue;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}

header {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Hope this work :)

Comment: Try to use Bootstrap it's more easy for beginners :)

Comment: I'd avoid putting the padding/margin on the h2 element because he's likely to insert an h2 tag elsewhere on the site. Just padding the wrapping div is a safer option.

Comment: Remove the margin as if you want add more then one h2 tag.

Comment: I actively discourage beginners using bootstrap because it really slows down the learning process, which is understanding how CSS properties work with each other...the only way to do this, short of having a photographic memory for the billions of CSS guides out there, is trial and error. Emphasis on error. Bootstrap gives you a fully fleshed out CSS file that helps people subvert a lot of stuff that's gonna come in handy later on when they decide they don't want to be beholden to a common framework anymore.

Comment: Dat true, but also the **expert** developers uses css library, it's kind of fast work, anyway you should understanding which code you write or read ;)

Comment: The **experts** aren't just starting to learn CSS though. In my work, I only use bootstrap when clients express preferences for features or appearances that bootstrap can provide without causing any added issues, because it's much faster for me to code a site from nothing in a lot of cases - and I also find that bootstrap websites tend to have a common appearance that you can pick up on whenever someone doesn't spend some time editing the theme into something unique.